# EditText's TextWatcher validator

Tags: android

I am doing a login `Activity` which basically has an `EditText` and two `Buttons`.
It looks like this:

[http://img249.imageshack.us/img249/9108/loginm.png http://img249.imageshack.us/img249/9108/loginm.png](http://img249.imageshack.us/img249/9108/loginm.png)

The `EditText` has a `TextWatcher` that validates the user with an `AsyncTask` that hits a webservice.

The code:

```
public class Login extends Activity {

    private EditText mUserNameET;
    private Drawable mCorrect;
    private Drawable mIncorrect;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private MyApp mApp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        mApp = (MyApp) getApplication();
        mUserNameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name_et);
        mUserNameET.addTextChangedListener(new LoginValidator());

        mCorrect = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.correct);
        mIncorrect = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.incorrect);
        mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
    }

    private class LoginValidator implements TextWatcher {

        private ValidateUserAsyncTask validator = new ValidateUserAsyncTask();

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            String value = s.toString();

            if ( value.length() == 0 )
                return;

            /* If it's running, cancel it. */
            /* Issue #2 */
            if ( AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING == validator.getStatus() ) {
                validator.cancel(true);
                validator = new ValidateUserAsyncTask();
            } else if ( AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED == validator.getStatus() ) {
                validator = new ValidateUserAsyncTask();
            }

            validator.execute(value);
            /* Issue #1 */
            mUserNameET.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, mProgressBar.getProgressDrawable(), null);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }
    }

    class ValidateUserAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if ( result ) {
                mUserNameET.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, mCorrect, null);
            } else {
                mUserNameET.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, mIncorrect, null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            return mApp.validateUser(params[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

My issues:

While the `AsyncTask` is working I want to show a ProgressBar inside the `EditText`.
I tried to do it using:

```
mUserNameET.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, mProgressBar.getProgressDrawable(), null);
```

but it doesn't work.

And I am also a bit worried about creating new instances of the `AsyncTask`. Am I leaking memory?

Comment: How do you get an `EditText` field with the `x` button to erase the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While the AsyncTask is working I want
>   to show a ProgressBar inside the
>   EditText

Try creating an `AnimationDrawable` representing your progress indicator, and use that with `setCompoundDrawables()`.

> And I am also a bit worried about
>   creating new instances of the
>   AsyncTask. Am I leaking memory?

Well, you can't reuse `AsyncTask` instances -- they are one-and-done. Bear in mind that `AsyncTask` uses a thread pool, and so you may have multiple `AsyncTasks` executing at one time, which may or may not be what you have in mind. I would consider waiting until there has been no typing for, say, 1 second, before doing the Web service stuff.

Comment: You mean I should replace the `ProgressBar` with an `AnimationDrawable` of my own?

What would you use to implement the one second wait, before hitting the WebService?

Comment: @Macarse: I don't know how you can get a `ProgressBar` *inside* an `EditText`, and certainly not via `setCompoundDrawables()`, as `ProgressBar` is a widget with a `LevelListDrawable` at its core. For the delay, I'd probably use `postDelayed()` in a fairly tight loop (e.g., 200ms). On every keystroke update a lastKeyTime value with `SystemClock.elapsedTime()`. The `Runnable` for `postDelayed()` sees if `lastKeyTime` was over 1 second -- if so, do the Web service; if not, reschedule the `Runnable`. This won't be perfect, but it beats you calling the Web service 5 times in parallel or something.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this post it woulb be helpfull.. Though it has been done for a button you can change it for a EditText..

http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-bring-spinner-at-end-of-button.html

http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2011_01_01_archive.html